# Retrieve logged user object and save it as a foreign key

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

While saving some data from the form I also need to add FK to the Record table. FK is User.Id.
I know how to save data from the input field on the form, but how can I set FK (int value) to this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
private User user;
```

Is there some way to retrieve object which relates to logged user and make something like this: record.setUser(user)?
I've googled it but I didn't manage to find how to achive this.

This is my entity class.

```
@Entity
public class Record implements java.io.Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int recordId;

    private String recordName;
    private String recordComment;
    private Date recordDate;
    private Integer price;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = true, updatable = false)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private User user;

    ......
    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "system_user")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int userId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;
    private String enabled;
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    private String confirmPassword;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "user_role")
    private Role role;

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval=true)
      @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
      private List<Record> records;

      public void addToRecord(Record record) {
        record.setUser(this);
        this.records.add(record);

      }

      ....
}
```

This is how I save data to DB:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/protected/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCost (@ModelAttribute("record") Record record,HttpSession session){
        User user = userManager.getUserObject(userManager.getUserId(session.getAttribute("currentUser").toString()));

        user.addToRecord(record);
        recordService.addRecord(record);
        return "redirect:/protected/purse";
    }
```

DAO:

```
 public void addRecord(Record record) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(record);

    }
```

UPDATE: problem was partially solved, code above works fine for me.

Comment: User object will contain List/Set  of Record object, It means you need to create first User object and then set all Records in User object then save User Object your problem will resolved. If your user object is null you can not proceed further.

Comment: I've added following code:

`public void addToRecord(Record record) { 
        record.setUser(this);
        this.records.add(record);
    }

User user = new User();
user.setId(1);
user.setName("admin");

... some other setters

user.addToRecord(record);
record.setUser(user);
recordService.addRecord(record);`

But FK wasn't saved and I haven't got any error messsag.

Comment: I've fixed it: just change @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = false, updatable = false) to @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = true, updatable = false)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to create User object and set the user object in a Record object using the below code

```
record.setUser(userObj);
```

and user foreign key will be automatically saved in database.

Comment: I've tried this before, but new User() object contains no information about logged user (it has null fields) and i've got validation error.

Comment: you have to set user information in user object and then save record object

Comment: Does it mean that I need to get user name, user id, password and other required data from session or DB query and then set it to the new User object? So, I can't retrieve whole object which relates to logged user, right?

Comment: I've found workaround: i've wrote following code     `public User getUserObject(int userId) {
        User user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, userId);
        return user;
    }` This method returns User object by it's id. But unfortunately i have such method calls in my controller now:  `User user = userManager.getUserObject(userManager.getUserId(session.getAttribute("currentUser").toString()));`